# How do I import Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I [followed the instructions on this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec--net-21297) which directed me to create a spec_helper.rb file using `rspec __init`. I then tried to require it in the same folder I initialized it in but I am receiving an error. My require statement is as follows: `require './spec_helper.rb'` and I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/user/spec/spec_helper.rb:17:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError)
```

Comment: Underscores?! Didn't see that anywhere there. Did you install it?

Comment: Would be great if you can post your files (the one with the `require 'spec_helper'` and the `spec_helper` file itself). It's hard to guess what might be missing when we cannot look at the files.